# Can Kofax Capture 10 process QR codes?

Tags: qr-code, capture, kofax

I am trying to determine whether or not Kofax Capture 10 is able to seperate documents and I seem to get some sort of a contradiction in Kofax Capture 10's documentation.

On one part, in the [Kofax Capture 10 Administrator's Guide](http://www.kofax.com/support/products/capture/10/documentation.php) (page 155), it says that the Enhanced Bar Code Engine can process the following 2-D bar codes: Aztec Code, Data Matrix, MaxiCode.

On another part, it says in a [Kofax Capture 10 Application Note](ftp://ftp.kofax.com/pub/support/capture/kc/10.1/product_documentation/application_notes/AppNote-Overview_of_Licensing_KC_10_to_use_EBC.pdf) (page 1) that the Enhanced Bar Code Engine can process the following 2-D bar codes: Aztec Code, Data Matrix, MaxiCode, PDF 417 and QR codes.

My question is: Can Kofax Capture 10 process QR codes with the help of the Enhanced Bar Code Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Kofax Capture 10 can use QR codes.  You can see that the asterisk indicates that it requires the EBC license.

[image: Bar Code Profile in Kofax Capture 10]

You can also see that QR-Code is listed in this article:
[QAID 2343](http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=2343)

Though the article only mentions up to version 9.0, you can see that this is just an oversight because it is a very old article that still refers to the product by the older "Ascent Capture" name.